# Azure OpenAI on nodeJS - Problems configuring Azure Openai

Tags: node.js, undefined, openai-api, no-response

My code was working properly untill I changed my API key to use openai through Azure, this was my old code:

```
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');


const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: apiKey,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function chatGPT(prompt,question,model_gpt) {
  try 
    { 
          const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
          model: model_gpt,
          messages: [
            {
              role: 'system',
              content: prompt
            },
            {
              role: 'user',
              content: question
            }
          ]
        });
        const completion = response.data.choices[0].message.content;
        return completion;
    }
```

now using Azure I had to use some new parameters:

```
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.placeholder_azure_APIKEY,
  api_type: "azure",
  api_base: "placeholder_azure_path",
  api_version: "placeholder_azure_version",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function chatGPT(prompt,question,model_gpt) {
    try 
    { 
          const response = await openai.ChatCompletion.create({
          engine: "placeHolder",
          messages: [
            {
              role: 'system',
              content: prompt
            },
            {
              role: 'user',
              content: question
            }
          ],
        });
        console.log(response);
        const completion = response.data.choices[0].message;
        console.log(completion);
        return completion;
    }
```

I tried using the python function but it doesn't work, but when I try to use the Node one: openai.createChatCompletion() I get an 401 error - wrong API Key used.

I'm sure my API keys and path are OK, the code works perfectly on python (using the same API Key), but I get these errors using NodeJS.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the error ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using try/catch, but there's no error getting caught :/

Comment: Have you tried to log: process.env.placeholder_azure_APIKEY

Comment: Please show how do you catch the error

Comment: seems like my catch was not working properly, now I get the same error on both:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Comment: It seems that `openai.ChatCompletion` is not a thing. Where did you get that code from? Isn't that a python api?

Comment: That's what chat GPT told me to use lol, yeah, The sample code was from a Python Code that i'm trying to translate to nodeJS

Comment: But trying to use createChatCompletion I get the 401 code, not sure why, because on my python script i'm using the same API keys and Paths. Does Azure has some security stuff that blocks specific languages???

Comment: Looks like `openai.ChatCompletion.create ` is for python. Try to use `createChatCompletion ` and make sure that your token env variable is defined